# Twitter Bootstrap Modals do not work when Another Bootstrap Model is already being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which I create as show below. I bring up the bootstrap modal and use it to edit with CodeMirror and CodeMirrorUI. When I get an error message from an jQuery `.ajax` call I call `BootstrapDialog.alert`. When I have success I call  `BootstrapDialog.show`. Both of these can be seen below.

Neither will appear when the bootstrap dialog is being shown. Why does this (not) happen?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="codeEditorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="codeEditorModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create/Edit Script</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <select class="selectpicker" name="idLanguage" id="selectLanguage" onchange="selectMode()" data-style="btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <option value="text/x-csharp">C#</option>
                    <option value="application/xquery">XQuery</option>
                    <option value="text/html">HTML/XML</option>
                    <option value="application/json">JSON</option>
                    <option value="text/x-sql">SQL</option>
                    <option value="text/javascript">JavaScript</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <textarea class="textareawidth form-control" id="code-textarea" rows="10" cols="120"></textarea>
                <br />
                <textarea class="textareawidth form-control" id="message-textarea" rows="5" cols="220"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="compileCodeEditorContents" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Compile</button>
                <button type="button" id="saveCodeEditorContents" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" id="showCode" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Show Code</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div id="divAjaxResult"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = null;
    var editorMessages = null;
    var editorText = "";
    var ruleLanguage = "";
    var idObject = ""
    var bCompile = false;

    function saveCodeEditorContents() {
        var scriptContents = editor.mirror.getValue();

        var codeEditorModel = {
            "ID": $("#ID").val(),
            "ScriptContents": scriptContents,
            "ScriptLanguage": $("#selectLanguage").val(),
            "Compile": bCompile
        };

        jsonString = JSON.stringify(codeEditorModel);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveModel", "EAMetaDataItemControlAttribute")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: jsonString,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var strMessage = result.output;
                var nPos = strMessage.indexOf("error");
                if (nPos >= 0) {
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
                        alert('You clicked: ' + result);
                    });
                    BootstrapDialog.alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: strMessage,
                        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
                        closable: true, // <-- Default value is true
                        buttonLabel: 'Close', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
                        callback: function (userAction) {
                            // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
                            strUserAction = 'Result is: ' + userAction;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (codeEditorModel.Compile == true) {
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
                        alert('You clicked: ' + result);
                    });
                    BootstrapDialog.show({
                        message: 'Compilation was successful.',
                        buttons: [{
                            label: 'Close',
                            action: function (dialogItself) {
                                dialogItself.close();
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                }
                //$('#divAjaxResult').html('<div class="success">' + message + '</div>');
            }
        });

        bCompile = false; // for next time this function is used just to save
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) it is mentioned that

> Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

I use [BootBox](http://bootboxjs.com/) which allows multiple modal dialog boxes.

Comment: Thanks that explains what I see is not something I did incorrectly. I will try the BootBox. Are you also saying that showing a bootstrap model will also prevent BootBox from working. As you can see in the code else if (codeEditorModel.Compile == true) {
                    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
                        alert('You clicked: ' + result);
                    });

Comment: Good point, but since beginning I haven't used raw bootstrap modals because of this limitation. So I'm not sure how they both would work together.